# Теоретический вопрос о проектировании JS на крупных проектах

Tags: javascript, шаблоны-проектирования

Ближе к делу, большая часть сайта написана на JS и этот самый JS поделен на объекты... К примеру, у галереи свой объект(ы) и набор методов, а у загрузки файлов свой, у кроппинга свой, у голосования свой и т.д.

Хочу подчеркнуть тот факт, что сайт написан на Histroy API и посему все работает без полной перезагрузки страницы.

Я думаю нецелесообразно будет загружать весь код JS один разом! Ведь пользователь может войти на сайт и ни разу не воспользоваться галереей или же не загрузить ни одного файла и т.д. и зачем в таком случае нагружать браузер лишним кодом, а так же принимать лишний трафик?
Не правильнее ли будет создать для каждой логики свой отдельный файл и по мере необходимости загружать его, а не весь код свалить в один файл и разом загрузить этот файл? К примеру, пользователь кликнул по картинке и скрипт загрузил код галереи и уже последующая работа с просмотром картинок, разумеется, не требует загрузки файла JS.
Друзья, поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequireJS, AMD - вот ключевые слова для направление вашего развития. Разбиваете приложение на модули и загружаете их по мере необходимости. Вот [пример](http://habrahabr.ru/post/209228/).

Comment: Спасибо, я обязательно почитаю сегодня об этом!